# NetSuite SuiteTalk: Search Filter with Custom Field Type

Tags: c#, netsuite

I am pulling my hair out on this one. I am attempting to filter a saved search with a custom field of type `SearchColumnSelectCustomField` (see XML of record below).

How do I convert this type properly, or what am I doing wrong here?
I'm not sure what I'm missing, but the error I always eventually hit is:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'NetSuite.com.netsuite.na1.webservices.SearchColumnSelectCustomField'
>   to 'NetSuite.com.netsuite.na1.webservices.SearchCustomField'
>   "

```
        TransactionSearchAdvanced transSearchAdv = new TransactionSearchAdvanced
        {
            savedSearchScriptId = "customsearch_mycustomsearch"
        };

        SearchColumnSelectCustomField cwoNumField = new SearchColumnSelectCustomField();
        cwoNumField.internalId = "custbody_consolidatedworkorder";

        transSearchAdv.criteria = new TransactionSearch
            {
                basic = new TransactionSearchBasic
                    {
                        //Error Here, on cwoNumField
                    customFieldList = new SearchCustomField[]{ cwoNumField }                                                    
                    }
            };
```

XML of search results, without filter criteria added:

```
                    <tranSales:basic xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                        <platformCommon:appliedToTransaction>
                            <platformCore:searchValue internalId="442671"/>
                            <platformCore:customLabel>SO #</platformCore:customLabel>
                        </platformCommon:appliedToTransaction>
                        <platformCommon:item>
                            <platformCore:searchValue internalId="315838"/>
                        </platformCommon:item>
                        <platformCommon:quantity>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>11.0</platformCore:searchValue>
                        </platformCommon:quantity>
                        <platformCommon:status>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>pendingBuild</platformCore:searchValue>
                        </platformCommon:status>
                        <platformCommon:transactionNumber>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>204</platformCore:searchValue>
                            <platformCore:customLabel>WO #</platformCore:customLabel>
                        </platformCommon:transactionNumber>
                        <platformCommon:customFieldList>
                            <platformCore:customField xsi:type="platformCore:SearchColumnBooleanCustomField" scriptId="custbody_buildcomplete" internalId="501">
                                <platformCore:searchValue>false</platformCore:searchValue>
                            </platformCore:customField>
                            /*********** field in question here *************/
                            <platformCore:customField xsi:type="platformCore:SearchColumnSelectCustomField" scriptId="custbody_consolidatedworkorder" internalId="500">
                                <platformCore:searchValue typeId="85" internalId="24"/>
                                <platformCore:customLabel>CWO #</platformCore:customLabel>
                            </platformCore:customField>
                        </platformCommon:customFieldList>
                    </tranSales:basic>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure WHY, but this is the answer. Can someone explain why a `SearchColumnSelectCustomField` field is searched via `SearchMultiSelectCustomField` ?

```
    TransactionSearchAdvanced transSearchAdv = new TransactionSearchAdvanced
    {
        savedSearchScriptId = "customsearch_woconsolidationsublist"
    };

    SearchMultiSelectCustomField cwoNumField = new SearchMultiSelectCustomField();
    cwoNumField.scriptId = "custbody_consolidatedworkorder";
    cwoNumField.@operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
    cwoNumField.operatorSpecified = true;
    cwoNumField.searchValue = new ListOrRecordRef[] { new ListOrRecordRef {internalId = "36"} };

    transSearchAdv.criteria = new TransactionSearch
        {
            basic = new customFieldList = new SearchCustomField[] { cwoNumField }                                          
                }
        };
```